# Runtime cast involving generic type parameter

Tags: c#, type-conversion, generic-variance

I'm building a command dispatch function, such that given an object deriving from a base class, it resolves (from an IoC container) a handler for the command type and sends the command object there for processing. My types look like this:

```
public abstract class CommandBase { }
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : CommandBase { 
    void Process(TCommand command);
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
public class TestCommand : CommandBase {
    // Some parameters
}
public class TestHandler : ICommandHandler<TestCommand> {
    public void Process(TestCommand command) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When I recieve a call, I can (almost) retrieve a matching handler from my container like this:

```
public ICommandHandler<T> GetHandler<T>(T command) where T : CommandBase
{
    var handlerInterface = typeof (ICommandHandler<>);
    var handlerType = handlerInterface.MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
    var handler = _scope.Resolve(handlerType) as ICommandHandler<T>;
    // Some magic?
    return handler; 
}
```

Which I want to call like this:

```
public void HandleCommand(CommandBase command) {
    var handler = GetHandler(command);
    handler.Process(command);
}
```

Problem is that the type parameter `T` is `CommandBase`, so the cast will be to `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>`, which isn't implemented by `TestHandler`, for instance. And no matter if I can cast it properly, I cannot return an implementation of `ICommandHandler<TestCommand>` when the `T=CommandBase`.

Is there some way around this? I'm not specifically locked in the GetHandler-method, anything that fits into the `HandleCommand` method is fine (I need to have a single entry point which accepts a base class, and I cannot do some switch/case monolith)

Comment: A good substitute for a switch/case monolith is to maintain a dictionary that relates the Command with the handlers. Then you just probe into the dictionary instead of hard-coding it with a switch.

Comment: @KeithPayne: Hm, not sure I see how - what type would I pull out of the dictionary?

Comment: What is the problem with what you've posted? The only thing that jumps out is that you could write `public void HandleCommand<T>(T command) where T : CommandBase ...`. But that depends. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @KeithPayne: The problem is that `T` will be `CommandBase`, not `TestCommand`, so I cannot cast `TestHandler` to `ICommandHandler<T>`, since `TestHandler` does not implement `ICommandHandler<CommandBase>`, but rather `ICommandHandler<TestCommand>`.